# Algorithm to find similarity of questions

Tags: algorithm, search, data-mining

I did same data mining and pulled all the interview questions from google and microsoft on glassdoor:
http://letschat.info/?p=34

http://letschat.info/?p=37

I have the two lists on there.

What I want to do is maybe pull a few other companies interview questions and try to find questions that similar among multiple sources.

I did some googling and I found this project:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/

and I could do the following:
http://javatechniques.com/blog/lucene-in-memory-text-search-example/

However this seems like overkill. Is there a simpler algorithm that could help me find similar questions? What algorithm does stack overflow use?

I was thinking of maybe generating a score based on the number of words that match between two questions and filter it that way.

I want to try to whittle the list of questions down to a list of unique number of questions.

Update:

I decided to use lucene. I put my entire list into an index and the iterate through the list and use lucene to search for 10 items like it. I then add up the score of the 10 results too see what questions were asked the most.

Here is the link to the actual code:http://letschat.info/ranking-of-reduced-amazon-questions/

It isn't too complicated. Here is an example of the results:
http://letschat.info/ranking-of-reduced-amazon-questions/

from the original source:
http://letschat.info/list-of-amazon-questions/

Comment: I like your idea of getting a score based on word match count.  Every time one question is added to the list, you should save the question along with the score to the db.  Then it's a simple query as new questions come in?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) on [tf-idf vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%2aidf), which is what Lucene implements, is a common (and pretty basic) way of measuring inter-document similarity. I'd try it if I were you (although your documents may be a bit short for it to function really well). Lucene does some nice text normalization as well.

Comment: I am not trying to do inter document similarity, but more trying to compare sentences, but I guess I might just use that method. Thanks

Comment: Sentences are just very short documents  TF-IDF and cosine similarity are the two standard technologies for textual similarity.

Answer (score 0):

[Simmetrics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) is a library that offers multiple string comparison algorithms. Check which ones works best for your needs.

One approach you might consider since these are "questions" is to use n-grams, improves accuracy.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it is actively developed